# SQL View - Challenge

Tags: sql, sql-server, view

I have a small challenge trying to create a "work in progress view"

I'm not convinced my statement is the best or correct and resulted in an error "Subquery returned more than 1 value"

I have three key tables;

- Tasks
- PurchaseOrderItem
- Resource

There is a unique reference field across all the tables e.g. Tasks.TA_SEQ, PurchaseOrderItem.TA_SEQ and Resource.TA_SEQ

I need to sum different totals from all these tables and the relationship are as follows;

- 1 Task - many PurchaseOrderItem
- 1 Task - many Resources

I need to sum all the Purchase order cost values (line items can vary) against active purchase orders for the Task and also sum all the resource cost (3 people - quantity can vary) against the task, any help would be much appreciated. if I can make it also any easier any advice would be appreciated.

Part of my Query as it stands;

```
 SELECT 
    dbo.F_TASKS.TA_SEQ, 
    (
    SELECT 
        SUM(POI_TOTAL) 
    From F_PO_ITEM 
    where POI_FKEY_TA_SEQ = dbo.F_TASKS.TA_SEQ 
        and POI_FKEY_POH_SEQ in 
            (
            select 
                POH_SEQ 
            from F_PO_HEAD 
            where POH_STATUS in ('DORMANT', 'ACTIVE')
            )
    ) AS [Pending PO Cost],
    dbo.F_TASKS.TA_PO_COST AS [PO Cost], 
    dbo.F_TASKS.TA_LABOUR_COST AS [Labour Cost],
    dbo.F_TASKS.TA_LABOUR_COST - SUM(dbo.F_TASK_TIME.TT_OTHER_COSTS) AS [New Labour Cost],

-----------Not Working from
(select 
    SUM(dbo.F_TASK_TIME.TT_OTHER_COSTS) 
from F_TASK_TIME 
where TT_FKEY_TA_SEQ = dbo.F_TASKS.TA_SEQ) + dbo.F_TASKS.TA_PO_COST AS [Subcontractor Costs], 
(SUM(dbo.F_TASK_TIME.TT_OTHER_COSTS + dbo.F_TASKS.TA_PO_COST)) * 0.12 AS [Subcontractor Uplift], 
((SUM(dbo.F_TASK_TIME.TT_OTHER_COSTS + dbo.F_TASKS.TA_PO_COST)) * 0.12) + (SUM(dbo.F_TASK_TIME.TT_OTHER_COSTS + dbo.F_TASKS.TA_PO_COST)) AS [Subcontractor Uplift Total]

-----------Not Working To 

FROM dbo.F_TASKS 
LEFT OUTER JOIN  dbo.F_TASK_TIME
    ON dbo.F_TASKS.TA_SEQ = dbo.F_TASK_TIME.TT_FKEY_TA_SEQ 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.F_PO_ITEM 
    ON dbo.F_TASKS.TA_SEQ = dbo.F_PO_ITEM.POI_FKEY_TA_SEQ 

WHERE (dbo.F_TASKS.TA_TASK_DESC = 'BREAKDOWN') 
    AND (dbo.F_TASKS.TA_PO_COST >= 0) 
    AND (dbo.F_TASKS.TA_STATUS IN ('ACTIVE', 'ASSIGNED', 'COMPLETE'))

GROUP BY dbo.F_TASKS.TA_PO_COST, dbo.F_TASKS.TA_SEQ, dbo.F_TASKS.TA_LABOUR_COST
```

Comment: First of is this mysql or SQLServer?

Comment: It can't be mysql. The brackets `[]` would complain.

Comment: dbo. -> 99.99% it's SQL Server :-).

Comment: apologies for the tagging error this is SQL Server

Comment: What have you done to determine which subquery is returning more than one value?

Comment: I changed the SUM(POI_TOTAL) statements which includes in select in statement as this was displaying the incorrect results. I tried to do the same for the SUM(TT_OTHER_COST) on a different table hoping it will work but then it resulted in the error.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than trying to fix your SQL, I'm going to propose a different wau of doing it. I couldn';t easily understand all the wheres in your selects in the select clause, so I've just done the first two.

This approach uses LEFT OUTER JOINs to queries which total by ta_seq. These are guaranteed to return only one row/ta_seq as that's how there're grouped:

```
SELECT 
    t.TA_SEQ,
    isnull(po.poi_total, 0) [Pending PO Cost],
    t.TA_PO_COST AS [PO Cost], 
    t.TA_LABOUR_COST AS [Labour Cost],
    t.TA_LABOUR_COST - isnull(tt.other_costs, 0) AS [New Labour Cost],
    -- other cols missed
FROM dbo.F_TASKS t
left outer join
(
    t.ta_seq, SUM(POI_TOTAL) poi_total
    From F_PO_ITEM  poi
    where POI_FKEY_POH_SEQ in 
    (
        select 
        POH_SEQ 
        from F_PO_HEAD 
        where POH_STATUS in ('DORMANT', 'ACTIVE')
    )
    group by t.ta_seq
) po on po.ta_seq = t.ta_seq
left outer join
(
    select tt.TT_FKEY_TA_SEQ ta_seq, sum(tt.tt_other_costs) other_costs
    from F_TASK_TIME tt
    group by tt.TT_FKEY_TA_SEQ
) tt on tt.ta_seq = t.ta_seq
WHERE (t.TA_TASK_DESC = 'BREAKDOWN') 
    AND (t.TA_PO_COST >= 0) 
    AND (t.TA_STATUS IN ('ACTIVE', 'ASSIGNED', 'COMPLETE'))
GROUP BY t.TA_PO_COST, t.TA_SEQ, t.TA_LABOUR_COST
```

I've also used table aliases as I find the schema.tablename format is making me blind (and not helping me decode the missed subqueries).
To put in the missing columns, just translate them into additional LEFT OUTER JOINs as above.

Cheers -